# Change \underline line thickness

Tags: beamer, macros, underline

As the title says, I would like to change the the thickness in the line produced by the command `\underline` (and avoiding the use of more packages) So far, I have managed to change its color using the macro

```
\def\underline#1{%
  \relax
  \ifmmode\@@underline{#1}%
  \else $\textcolor{NavyBlue}{\@@underline{\hbox{#1}}}\m@th$\relax\fi}
\makeatother
```

I have been reading some posts published here but none of them offers a direct solution using the same command `\underline`. I have also been looking for the primitive definition of `\@@underline`but it is not the `latex.ltx` file nor any of the others file I have checked.

Is there no way, really? Why is it so difficult?

Thank you

P.S: The command is to use it ine beamer, just in casy it matters.

Comment: `\@@underline` is the LaTeX name for the `\underline` primitive. That primitive doesn't allow much customization, the line thickness is the default line thickness defined by your math fonts (the same thickness is used e.g. for the fraction line) You could change the relevant parameters from the math font temporarily, but at that point it is probably simpler to just implement a macro like `\underline` from scratch.

Comment: To elaborate on the parameter, it is `\fontdimen8\textfont3`, and regarding "temporarily", the setting at the end of a math formula will apply to the whole formula. Moreover, fontdimen settings are implicitly global, so can't be undone by grouping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `\underline`-macro does typeset things within a `\hbox` if not in math-mode.

This implies that hyphenation and line-breaking is not needed with the material that is to be underlined.

It also implies that everything may be typeset in its natural with, without applying some stretching/shrinking for having material fit nicely into lines automatically broken in non-restricted horizontal mode.

Thus, if not in math-mode, something like the following might be sufficient:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, usenames]{xcolor}

\newcommand\MyUnderLineWithNoLinebreaks[5]{%
  % #1 - text to underline
  % #2 - color of rule
  % #3 - color of text
  % #4 - distance between rule and baseline of line of text
  % #5 - thickness of rule
  \protect\leavevmode
  {%
    \color{#2}%
    \vtop{%
      \hbox{\color{#3}#1}%
      \kern-\prevdepth
      \kern#4\relax
      \hrule height #5\relax
      \kern-#4\relax
      \kern-#5\relax
    }%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}
Text Text \MyUnderLineWithNoLinebreaks{Bla xypqg}{NavyBlue}{ForestGreen}{.3mm}{.3pt}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text \MyUnderLineWithNoLinebreaks{Bla xypqg}{Melon}{WildStrawberry}{.75mm}{2mm}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

This way, the underline will cover up/strike out parts of letters that have some depth. (In the picture the blue does cover up the green.)

If you wish parts of letters that have some depth to cover up the underline, you can try it this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, usenames]{xcolor}

\newlength\scratchlength

\newcommand\MyUnderLineWithNoLinebreaks[5]{%
  % #1 - text to underline
  % #2 - color of rule
  % #3 - color of text
  % #4 - distance between rule and baseline of line of text
  % #5 - thickness of rule
  \protect\leavevmode
  {%
    \color{#2}%
    \vtop{%
      \settoheight\scratchlength{#1}%
      \hbox{\phantom{#1}}%
      \kern-\prevdepth
      \kern#4\relax
      \hrule height #5\relax
      \kern-#4\relax
      \kern-#5\relax
      \kern-\scratchlength
      \hbox{\color{#3}#1}%
    }%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}
Text Text \MyUnderLineWithNoLinebreaks{Bla xypqg}{NavyBlue}{ForestGreen}{.3mm}{.3pt}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
Text Text \MyUnderLineWithNoLinebreaks{Bla xypqg}{Melon}{WildStrawberry}{.75mm}{2mm}
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

(In the picture the green does cover up the blue.)

If you don't like the restrictions (natural width, i.e., no shrinking/stretching, no hyphenation, no automatic breaking of lines), have a look at the [soul](https://ctan.org/pkg/soul)-package.

Comment: Could you please tell me the difference between the two pictures? I'm afraid I can't see anyone

Comment: @Dog_69 With one picture the blue underline runs on the green letters p,q and q and covers parts of them which reach beyond the baseline of the line. With the other picture the parts of those green letters that reach beyond the baseline cover the blue underline. If you don't see it on the pictures, compile the examples and view the letters p, q and g within the resulting pdf-files with a very large zoom-factor.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I have accepted the answer, but I think I will use the package `soul', as you say. Thank you!

Comment: @Dog_69 Using soul might indeed be the better alternative. The manual of that package has a section  "how the package works" where you can learn how to use the underlying macros of the soul-package for writing your own underlinining-mechanism/driver (where you probably also can use `\hrule` or the like and specify the underline's thickness...)

Comment: I have been playing with the paraemeters of your definition and I have found a nice combination. I am satisfied and I don't need the `soul' package for the moment. I cannot but I would give you another +1. Thanks again.